# Flyway couldn't find datasource in spring boot multi-datasource app

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, datasource, flyway

I have multiple data sources in spring boot application. My application is configured as

```
spring:
  profiles: default
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${pr.db.host}:${pr.db.port}/${pr.db.name}
    username: ${pr.db.user}
    password: ${pr.db.password}
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    test-on-borrow: true
    test-while-idle: true
    validation-query: select 1;
    maxActive: 1
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    generate-ddl: false
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        ddl-auto: validate
        hbm2ddl:
          import_files:

otherdb:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${pf.db.host}:${pf.db.port}/${pf.db.name}
    username: ${pf.db.user}
    password: ${pf.db.password}
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    test-on-borrow: true
    test-while-idle: true
    validation-query: select 1;
    maxActive: 1
```

Then, I have created two classes `DBOneConfig` and `OtherDBConfig` in my `com.company.project.dbconfig` package.

The `DBOneConfig` looks like this (note that I have already marked it as `FlywayDataSource`)

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
  basePackages = {"com.company.project.repo"}
)
public class DbOneConfig {
  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "dataSource")
  @FlywayDataSource
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    return dataSource;
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
    EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
    @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder
      .dataSource(dataSource)
      .packages("com.worldgaming.pennyrama.domain")
      .persistenceUnit("pennyrama")
      .build();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
    @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
  }
}
```

Now, when I run the project, I get following exception

```
[2016-06-20 21:38:56.196] [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at com.worldgaming.pennyrama.Application.main(Application.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:56)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1386)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [main] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 30 seconds, none available[size:1; busy:1; idle:0; lastwait:30000].
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:681)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:185)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:50)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please read the error message again. The datasource has been found and is being used but you only have one connection available in the pool and it's already used or something `Unable to fetch a connection in 30 seconds, none available[size:1; busy:1; idle:0; lastwait:30000].`

Comment: thanks. I figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you need to have two distinct classes for each of the datasorces. Each of them should also refer to their settings in the Repository folder and their entities. This way, when it's used, it will know which datasources is used.

usually ,when you use multi datasources hibernate do not convert camelcase to underline, you should use :

```
@Table(name = "investor_destination")
@Column(name = "dest_type")
```